# javascript execution events order

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with a simple javascript.
I would like to display a html div for 2 seconds.
I tried the following code but instead of display my div for 2 seconds on execution my div is displayed after 2 second.

```
//show my element
document.getElementById("alertProg").style.display=block;

//wait
var ms=2000;
ms += new Date().getTime();
while (new Date() < ms){}
```

How can I solve this problem?

**EDIT:** the problem isn'nt only in a time delay but if I call a function between the change of display value the div isn't displayed correctly. example:

```
document.getElementById("alertProg").style.display='block';
myFunction();
document.getElementById("alertProg").style.display='none';
```

as result myFunction is executed but alertProg is always hidden.

Comment: `var elem = document.getElementById("alertProg");
elem.style.display = 'block';
setTimeout(function() {
  elem.style.display = 'none';
}, 2000);`

Comment: thanks Rayon Dabre

Answer (score 2):

You should use [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) for that :

```
var div = document.getElementById('alertProg');
var ms = 2000;

div.style.display = 'block';
setTimeout(function(){
   div.style.display = 'none';
},ms);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout function.  It has two parameters. The first one is your function, the other's time (ms). When time is up which is defined, function will run.

[More details here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

```
var ms = 2000;
document.getElementById("alertProg").style.display='block';
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("alertProg").style.display='none';
},ms);
```